# Excel add-in removed without consent

Tags: python, vba, excel, xlwings

I have programmed an excel add-in in VBA that makes calls to a MySQL server using python. My problem is the following :

every once in a while, for no apparent reason, the add-in gets removed from the developer tab, and I can't access its code anymore. The way around this problem is to uninstall and reinstall the add-in (Files->OPtions->Add-ins->Go..). Since it is quite tedious, I am reaching out for help.

[Opening a existing file with formulas from my add-in, I first get the following warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsXf1.png)

[Leading to this when trying to edit the links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93xAV.png)

Unfortunately the editing fails and gives an error message

Then, the formulas stay broken and fail to call the add-in, just like it wasn't found, and i have to remove it and re-import it for the workbook to function.

Has any VBA developer run into the issue before?

Comment: Nope. But you can actually make an add-in self install like an exe file. Not that it will really help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it IF I am facing the same issue as yours

1. Close all open workbooks in Excel
2. Create a new subroutine called `Auto_Open` in a Blank Excel File
3. Add the code which is mentioned at the bottom of this post
4. Save it to `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` after you have entered, tested and verified the code. *The path may vary depending on the OS that you are using*.

And you are done. Next time Excel launches, it will check if the Add-In is installed and if not then it will install it.

**Untested**

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    If IsAddinLoaded("Your Add-In Name") = False Then
        With Application
            .AddIns.Add "Filepath to your Add-In", False
            .AddIns("Your Add-In Name").Installed = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function IsAddinLoaded(AddinName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsAddinLoaded = Len(Workbooks(AddIns(AddinName).Name).Name) > 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it the fact that the file lies in the XLSTART folder that automatically makes it run everytime I launch excel? Also, should I save it as an add-in or a simple macro-enabled workbook?